# Can I shorten this code with a loop in C#?

Tags: c#

I have this code written in C# but looks kind of "bad" and I would like to shorten it somehow and keep it clean and simple.
All this code works pretty fine but I want to know if there's any other way I can achieve the same thing.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the firstLine has a bad date format attached with it, so it is like this: `"This_is_my_first_line_20220126"`. So I split the string and then only join it with the corrected date. The problem is that I can never know how long the new string would be and I don't want to handle the code like this and go up to 100 parts.

Here's my code:

```
string correctDate = "26012022";
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("text.txt");
string firstLine = lines.FirstOrDefault();
//note: firstLine looks like this: This_is_my_first_line_20220126
string[] sub = firstLine.Split('_');
string name="";

if(sub.Length==2)
  name = sub[0]+"_"+sub[1]+"_"+correctDate;
else if(sub.Length==3)
  name = sub[0]+"_"+sub[1]+"_"+sub[2]+"_"correctDate;
...
else if(sub.Length==20)
  name = sub[0]+"_"+ ... "_" + sub[19];
```

Now, my final name value should be `"This_is_my_line_26012022"` but I want it to depend on the length of the given string. So far I know that the maximum length would go up to 20 but I don't want my code to look like this. Can I shorten it somehow?

Comment: You can use [string.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-6.0)

Comment: `name = firstLine + "_" + correctDate`?..

Comment: Why are you splitting the line in the first place?

Comment: `firstLine + "_" + correctDate` would give you the same result

Comment: 1) why splitting and then combining the string parts with the same separator again? 2) looks like you want only to append the date, why not appending it to the original string? 3) why is the date missing in the last if clause? is this on purpose?

Comment: I forgot to mention that firstLine has a bad date format like "This_is_my_Line_20220125"
So I split the date part and then I want to join the rest of the string with the new corrected date type. The problem is that I don't know how long a new string would be...

Comment: please edit your post with this new information. you could find the index of the las `"_"` and use `string.Subtring` to get rid of the date, then simply append the new one

Comment: Seems like you could use `String.Join('_', sub)`.

Comment: Anyway, replace the Last sub[sub.Lenght] with the correcteddate and join

Comment: This  is not a code review site, also you should have bigger problems to worry about

Comment: @TheGeneral, what do you mean by ` you should have bigger problems to worry about `?

Comment: My point is, this not the right site for a code review. How your code looks is irrelevant here. Apart from allocations there will be negligible performance issues unless this is on a hot path in a massively scaled environment. Additionally there a no metrics to answer your question Apart from id like it to be silky smooth. Likely the whole solution and problem should be rethought and could be better, who knows? The short of this being, is if you want a code review talk to your senior developers or see the code review site  )

Comment: @TheGeneral, okay I get it now. I thought it would be a good idea and I would learn something new and upgrade my coding skills by writing them shorter and simpler instead of just running it a 100 times. Thank you for your time and efforts to everyone. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can find the [LastIndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netframework-4.8#system-string-lastindexof(system-string)) the underscore and drop the date by using [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8#system-string-substring(system-int32-system-int32)):

```
string firstLine = "This_is_my_first_line_20220126";
string correctDate = "26012022";
string correctString = firstLine.Substring(0, firstLine.LastIndexOf("_") + 1) + correctDate;
```

Comment: Nice and simple, this is what I really needed. Silly me that I never though of just trimming the string to the last part and trimmed the whole string into an array. Thank you very much. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Still a little perplexed with the split aproach, but this a way to join back all elements

```
string name = string.Join("_", sub.Take(sub.Length - 1).Append(correctDate));
```

Or use the substring method (and no need of all that split & join)

```
name = firstLine.Substring(0, firstLine.LastIndexOf("_") +1) + correctDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

> I forgot to mention that firstLine has a bad date format like "This_is_my_Line_20220125"

If you want to correct just the first line:

```
string correctDate = "26012022";
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("text.txt");
lines[0] = lines[0][..^8] + correctDate;
```

`[..^8]` uses C# 9's "indices and ranges" feature, that allows for a more compact way of taking a substring. It means "from the start of the string, up to the index 8 back from the end of the string".

If you get a wiggly line and possibly a messages like "... is not available in C# version X" you can use the older syntax, which would be more like `lines[0] = lines[0].Remove(lines[0].Length - 8) + correctDate;`

If you want to correct all lines:

```
string correctDate = "26012022";
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("text.txt");
for(int x = 0; x < lines.Length; x++)
  lines[x] = lines[x][..^8] + correctDate;
```

If the incorrect date isn't always 8 characters long, you can use LastIndexOf('_') to locate the last `_`, and snip it to that point